# How to append to a dictionary from the second value of a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm asking this question because im stuck with it for a while and couldn't find any sort of proper solution on this community or anywhere.
I have a pandas data frame from where I need to create a dictionary in such a way that the first value of a column forms the first key value pair and the rest forms the rest of the key value pairs. The dataframe I have looks like this

```
    created                  count
0   2016-12-31 00:00:00      34
1   2016-01-31 00:00:00      1 
2   2016-02-31 00:00:00      5
```

Now the desired output is something like this

```
return {
'avg_active_percentage' : 79.2,
'past_trend': '39,34,23,12'
}
```

I have managed to solve the first part of the question by using the iloc[] function. The second part of it is the tricky part. Also a little calculation was done to get a percentage value and then rounding it off to the nearest decimal value

```
a['count']= a['count']*100/total_number_users
a['count']=a['count'].round(1)
b=a['count'].iloc[0]
b=str('%.2f'% b)
result={'average_active_percentage': b}
i=1
c=[]
c=a['count'].iloc[i]
while count in a['count']:
    i=i+1
    c.append(a['count'].iloc[i].round(1))    
result['past trend']=c
result
```

However i am getting an error with the above code saying

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

Comment: What is `a['count'].dtype` ?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to perform division on a variable that contains a string. Also, in future, please post the full stack trace. It makes it easier to immediately narrow down on the issue (for example, the exact line you're getting an error on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
#cast to numeric, if problematic value replace by NaN
a['count'] = pd.to_numeric(a['count'], errors='coerce')

total_number_users = 250
#cast to string, create list with all values without first 
L = a['count'].round(1).astype(str).iloc[1:].tolist()
print (L)
['1', '5']
#create string with list
past_trend = ','.join(L)
print (past_trend)
1,5

a['count']= a['count']*100/total_number_users
a['count']=a['count'].round(1)
b=a['count'].iloc[0]
b=str('%.2f'% b)

result={'average_active_percentage': b}
#print (result)

result['past trend']=past_trend
print (result)
{'average_active_percentage': '13.60', 'past trend': '1,5'}
```